# What does the following statement in C++ mean

Tags: c++, c

What does the statement

```
WidthT getwidth(void);
```

mean? To me, this says that `getwidth` is called and is of type `WidthT`. Is this correct?

Comment: Please make the title of your question more relevant to the content of the question.  "I know this is easy for C/C++ programmers" may well be accurate, but it doesn't begin to describe the content of the question.

Comment: Don't try to write multi-language source files. I believe the proper prototype in C++ (`WidthT getwidth()`) is somewhat different than the proper prototype in C (`WidthT getwidth(void)`). Using the C prototype for C++ is nothing but a kludge.

Comment: And using both `c` and `c++` tags is, in most cases, sign of ignoration about differences between those languages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement you're giving is a declaration that;

> There exists a function called getWidth that takes no parameters and
>   returns something of type WidthT.

It's called a forward declaration and is usually used to tell the code following it to assume that the function exists somewhere else and will work to call.

Answer (score 5):

It is a [function prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype) that usually is put on header files.The prototype gives a lot of information about the function.

Answer (score 4):

It's a declaration of a function prototype.

It means, there's a function called `getwidth` that takes no arguments and returns a value of the type `WidthT`.

The function is not defined here, but it's probably defined somewhere else - maybe in another file.